# custom constraints validation and Null

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I have custom constraint, with following logic:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(City city, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    boolean result = (city.getId() > 0 || (city.getName() != null && city.getName() != "")); 
    return result;
}
```

This works well when I need to check `City` instance from create operation (this field is required so it can be guarded by `@NotNull`).

But when I need to update an object which contains `City` instance, this field is optional. So even if I group `@NotNull` constraint to `Create` operation, I still need a way to check if it is null and (if it's not) if it's a valid object.

Can I do it without creating another constraint with both checks?

Thanks for you answers.

Comment: Are you combining this with a database back-end? If so are you updating the whole row or just the columns that are changed? (Look into MERGE)

Comment: no, i have UserModel  with validation in front of UserEntity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finished with editing my first constraint with `OR null` check.

```
@Override
    public boolean isValid(Country country, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean result = (country==null||
                             country.getId() > 0 || 
                             (country.getName() != null && country.getName() != ""));
        return result;
    }
```

And in bean

```
    @NotNull(groups = Create.class)
    @ValidCountry(groups = {Create.class, Update.class})
    private Country country;
```